# angular js select box comes empty option at first

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, select

I am using angular 1.6.4 I want to display ages in select box so get values from controller, I use below code, but first field will come empty? please help me how to solve it

```
  <select ng-model="agefrom" name="agefrom" id="agefrom" class="select" style="width: 45%">
    <option ng-repeat="age in ages" ng-value="age">{{age}}</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Read the documentation about [ngValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) and you should understand where you went wrong. Next, read the docs about [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) and you'll know how to do it right

Answer (score 1):

the first option comes empty because you did not select a ngModel. add value to `ngModel` and also use `ng-options` instead `ng-repeat`

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.ages = [2,3,4];

$scope.agefrom = $scope.ages[0]

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <select ng-model="agefrom" name="agefrom" id="agefrom" class="select" style="width: 45%" ng-options="age as age for age in ages"> 
 </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use ng-init like this

```
<select ng-init="agefrom = ages[0]" 
    ng-model="agefrom" 
    name="agefrom" id="agefrom" class="select" 
    style="width: 45%">
    <option ng-repeat="age in ages" ng-value="age">{{age}}</option>
</select>
```